# 502 Error Nginx +php-fpm 8 issue with API access

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, nginx, fpm

In my new Amazon linix machine after configured ,I can't get Nginx working with the API as it is supposed to. The current error is that '**`curl localhost/api' returns a 502`**.

```
[root@ip-ec2-user]# curl localhost:8872/api
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.20.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**Nginx Logs**

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log /var/log/nginx/error.log
        ==> /var/log/nginx/access.log <==
        
        ==> /var/log/nginx/error.log <==
        2022/05/24 08:14:50 [emerg] 10638#10638: bind() to 0.0.0.0:8872 failed (98: Address already in use)
        2022/05/24 08:14:50 [emerg] 10638#10638: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
        2022/05/24 08:14:50 [emerg] 10638#10638: bind() to 0.0.0.0:81 failed (98: Address already in use)
        2022/05/24 08:14:50 [emerg] 10638#10638: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

**Nginx .conf**

```
    user nginx;
    worker_processes auto;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;
    
    # Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
    include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
    
    events {
        worker_connections 1024;
    }
    
    http {
        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    
        sendfile            on;
        tcp_nopush          on;
        tcp_nodelay         on;
        keepalive_timeout   65;
        types_hash_max_size 4096;
    
        include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type        application/octet-stream;
    
        # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
        # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
        # for more information.
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    
        server {
            listen       80;
            listen       [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;
            server_name  _;
            root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    
            # Load configuration files for the default server block.
            include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    
            error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /404.html {
            }
    
            error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
            }
        }
    
    # Settings for a TLS enabled server.
    #
    #    server {
    #        listen       443 ssl http2;
    #        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
    #        server_name  _;
    #        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #
    #        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
    #        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
    #        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    #        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    #        ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
    #        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    #
    #        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    #        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    #
    #        error_page 404 /404.html;
    #            location = /40x.html {
    #        }
    #
    #        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #            location = /50x.html {
    #        }
    #    }
    
    }
    
    
    # configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:
    
    types {
        text/html                                        html htm shtml;
        text/css                                         css;
        text/xml                                         xml;
        image/gif                                        gif;
        image/jpeg                                       jpeg jpg;
        application/javascript                           js;
        application/atom+xml                             atom;
        application/rss+xml                              rss;
    
        text/mathml                                      mml;
        text/plain                                       txt;
        text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor                 jad;
        text/vnd.wap.wml                                 wml;
        text/x-component                                 htc;
    
        image/png                                        png;
        image/svg+xml                                    svg svgz;
        image/tiff                                       tif tiff;
        image/vnd.wap.wbmp                               wbmp;
        image/webp                                       webp;
        image/x-icon                                     ico;
        image/x-jng                                      jng;
        image/x-ms-bmp                                   bmp;
    
        font/woff                                        woff;
        font/woff2                                       woff2;
    
        application/java-archive                         jar war ear;
        application/json                                 json;
        application/mac-binhex40                         hqx;
        application/msword                               doc;
        application/pdf                                  pdf;
        application/postscript                           ps eps ai;
        application/rtf                                  rtf;
        application/vnd.apple.mpegurl                    m3u8;
        application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml             kml;
        application/vnd.google-earth.kmz                 kmz;
        application/vnd.ms-excel                         xls;
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject                    eot;
        application/vnd.ms-powerpoint                    ppt;
        application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics      odg;
        application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation  odp;
        application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet   ods;
        application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text          odt;
        application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
                                                         pptx;
        application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
                                                         xlsx;
        application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                                                         docx;
        application/vnd.wap.wmlc                         wmlc;
        application/x-7z-compressed                      7z;
        application/x-cocoa                              cco;
        application/x-java-archive-diff                  jardiff;
        application/x-java-jnlp-file                     jnlp;
        application/x-makeself                           run;
        application/x-perl                               pl pm;
        application/x-pilot                              prc pdb;
        application/x-rar-compressed                     rar;
        application/x-redhat-package-manager             rpm;
        application/x-sea                                sea;
        application/x-shockwave-flash                    swf;
        application/x-stuffit                            sit;
        application/x-tcl                                tcl tk;
        application/x-x509-ca-cert                       der pem crt;
        application/x-xpinstall                          xpi;
        application/xhtml+xml                            xhtml;
        application/xspf+xml                             xspf;
        application/zip                                  zip;
    
        application/octet-stream                         bin exe dll;
        application/octet-stream                         deb;
        application/octet-stream                         dmg;
        application/octet-stream                         iso img;
        application/octet-stream                         msi msp msm;
    
        audio/midi                                       mid midi kar;
        audio/mpeg                                       mp3;
        audio/ogg                                        ogg;
        audio/x-m4a                                      m4a;
        audio/x-realaudio                                ra;
    
        video/3gpp                                       3gpp 3gp;
        video/mp2t                                       ts;
        video/mp4                                        mp4;
        video/mpeg                                       mpeg mpg;
        video/quicktime                                  mov;
        video/webm                                       webm;
        video/x-flv                                      flv;
        video/x-m4v                                      m4v;
        video/x-mng                                      mng;
        video/x-ms-asf                                   asx asf;
        video/x-ms-wmv                                   wmv;
        video/x-msvideo                                  avi;
    }
    
    # configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/global.conf:
    server {
        listen 8872;
        root /var/www/mysite.com-api/public;
        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        }
        location ~ ^/(index|captcha)\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 512k;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 240;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            return 404;
        }
        error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com-error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com-access.log;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/mysite.com-ui;
        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8872;
        }
        location /admin {
            rewrite  ^/admin/(.+)$ /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:81;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
        error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com-ui-error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com-ui-access.log;
    }
    server {
        listen 81;
        root /var/www/mysite.com-admin-ui;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com-admin-ui-error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com-admin-ui-access.log;
    }
    
    # configuration file /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params:
    
    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
    
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;
    
    fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;
    
    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
    
    # PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
    fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
    
    # configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/php-fpm.conf:
    # PHP-FPM FastCGI server
    # network or unix domain socket configuration
    
    upstream php-fpm {
            server unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
    }
```

**sudo netstat -plant | grep 80**

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7450/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      7450/nginx: master
```

**sudo ps aux | grep 'php'**

```
root      2854  0.0  0.2 252816  5428 ?        Ss   May24   0:02 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php-fpm.conf)
apache    2855  0.0  0.2 252816  5132 ?        S    May24   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
apache    2856  0.0  0.2 252816  5132 ?        S    May24   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
apache    2857  0.0  0.2 252816  5132 ?        S    May24   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
apache    2858  0.0  0.2 252816  5132 ?        S    May24   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
apache    2859  0.0  0.2 252816  5132 ?        S    May24   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
root      7500  0.0  0.0 119420   956 pts/0    S+   07:26   0:00 grep --color=auto php
```

**sudo systemctl status systemd-journald**

```
● systemd-journald.service - Journal Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-05-24 16:26:16 UTC; 21h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-journald.service(8)
           man:journald.conf(5)
 Main PID: 1148 (systemd-journal)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-journald.service
           └─1148 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald

May 24 16:26:16 ip-.ec2.internal systemd-journal[1148]: Runtime journal is using 8.0M (max allowed 97.7M, trying to leave 146.5M free of 961.0M availabl…it 97.7M).
May 24 16:26:16 ip-.ec2.internal systemd-journal[1148]: Journal started
May 24 16:26:16 ip-.ec2.internal systemd-journal[1148]: Permanent journal is using 32.0M (max allowed 3.9G, trying to leave 4.0G free of 37.6G available…mit 3.9G).
May 24 16:26:16 ip-.ec2.internal systemd-journal[1148]: Time spent on flushing to /var is 120.088ms for 549 entries.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

I had change nginx ipv6 lister port and  apache state to disable. But nothing works.
Looks like both Nginx and Php-fpm working fine , but I'm not able to figure it out what's wrongs here?

Is there a possibility that there is some problem with the conf.d/global.conf file, its throw 502?

can anyone suggest how to troubleshoot or fix it?

Comment: can you see the log using journalctl -xe ?

Comment: I did check it status as  Active: active (running)